# Temporarily leaving the workplace to travel

Tags: professionalism, employer-relations, time-off

I am a recent college graduate and I am interested in living in a big city (Chicago) for a span of 3-4 months (a summer). Currently, I am employed (full time for 5 months/was an intern before that for 4.5 months) as a software developer.

No one reports to me. The projects I have in place have one person assigned to each to support them, so they would not be doomed if I was gone for a little while.

I do plan on searching for related work in the software industry or working a non-corporate job (bartender, etc). Strictly because I will need income, not because I am searching for opportunities away from my employer I am currently at.

Since I am new to the corporate world, I am aware that there are potential repercussions that I am not aware of that will affect the business, and I do not want to cause any negative actions or connotations from this. I also want to ensure my position will be here when I return. My current employer frowns on remote connection/working from home and has clear guidelines regarding leaves.

1. Can I make this case to my manager?
2. If they agree, should I try and get some document that states explicitly I will have my job upon return?
3. Is this a common thing to happen, or am I way out of line?
4. If they agree, what will happen if I ask for a promotion when I return if I feel I have gained the knowledge to surpass my current role?

I am concerned because while any **good** manager would tell someone in my shoes that if it's something I want to do, then I should do it, I do understand the position of him as a manager, and his job as a manager, which, among many other things, is to ensure the work is getting done by the people (s)he oversees.

The case I can plead:

1. I plan on returning (possibly with even more knowledge than I left with)
2. I have received good reviews by my previous manager and mentor
3. I have received good reviews by my current manager
4. I have done what is asked of me and more, always willing and asking to take on new tasks and assist in other projects to get more experience
5. Always on time, never taking sick days, only take 30 minute lunches, etc.
6. Along with #4, I continually ask how I can further advance myself within the company and show eagerness/motivation

Comment: __Comments removed.  Again.__  Please avoid using comments for extended discussion. Instead, please use [chat]. Comments are intended to help improve a post. Please see [What "comments" are not...](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not) for more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, I don't think you have established enough of a track record with your employer to start proposing such a leave of absence. While you list some nice attributes in your "case I can plead" list, it's only over 5 months. In the business scheme of things, that's a "nice start" but seldom worthy of a promotion or granted leave of absence (yet).

You might need to be more patient. Sometimes it's a difficult transition from college where you get to work for a semester then take a break, to the work life where you get a few weeks vacation, but otherwise just work. You might want to give it some time, to show your current and future employers that you have made the transition.

Then again, yours might just be the kind of company that is happy to have people take a leave of absence in their first year of employment and come back with a promotion waiting for them. I've never heard of such a thing, but one never knows.

> Can I make this case to my manager?

Of course, you can make any case you like. I've never seen this happen in all the years I've worked. But perhaps your company does this sort of thing all the time. You won't know unless you ask.

> If they agree, should I try and get some document that states
>   explicitly I will have my job upon return?

Definitely. Any leave of absence should be documented. And all the terms of that leave should be clear to you, and to the company.

You can try, but you may not get exactly what you are looking for. Companies that grant leaves often leave themselves the right to stop holding a position open, if business conditions change sufficiently, if you don't return according to schedule, etc, etc.

If they agree to leave, they will certainly spell out the details of how it will work.

> Is this a common thing to happen, or am I way out of line?

I've never heard of a 3-4 month leave being granted for someone who had only been working full-time for 5 months. If you tell us that it was actually granted - it would be the first I've ever heard of. There's a first time for everything.

> If they agree, what will happen if I ask for a promotion when I return
>   if I feel I have gained the knowledge to surpass my current role?

Really? You want to go away for 3-4 months and expect to be able to ask for a promotion when you get back? Wow!

I guess anything's possible. I would bet against your getting a promotion, though. What could you possibly do away from the company for 3-4 months away that would warrant a promotion after 8-9 months of employment.

> I am concerned because while any good manager would tell someone in my
>   shoes that if it's something I want to do, then I should do it

I'm not sure I agree with the premise behind that statement. It sounds more like what a college buddy might say, than what someone who had your career progression in mind might say.

You don't need your manager's permission to quit. So if you feel strongly that you need to take a summer break after 5 months of full-time work, then you always have the option of leaving. If I were your manager (and I cared about your career), I'd advise against it. It's what some call a "career-limiting move".

Answer (score 7):

I want you to understand how extraordinarily rare such a request being successfully negotiated is. In almost 40 years in the workplace (working at large companies, government organizations, small privately held companies and medium companies) I have never seen anyone have something like this granted. I have heard of some senior level people (VP level and above) who have gotten this sort of leave before I got there and only one of those and she was ill. I have seen a more junior person fired because her short-term disability ran out and she was still sick and they needed to replace her position because the work was not getting done.

I do know someone who has taken time off from work, but in every case, he had to resign his position. Luckily for him, he has way beyond outstanding skills, so he never had trouble finding a new job when he was ready to go back to work. If you are an average employee, that could be an issue the second time you do such a thing. Hiring officials aren't wild about people who quit to do nothing for a few months. Especially if they show a pattern of doing that.

If you do this, your company will be without you for a period of months. In the meantime they can't hire someone new to do the job if you are coming back. Nor can they be sure you will come back.  If they can do without you for 3-6 months, then they will feel that they don't need your position.  This is a business decision. Who cares what your personal desires are. If the best guy I ever met at his job had to resign to take some time off, assume you will too.  Also assume that the longer you are unemployed the harder it is to get another job. Many companies won't consider the unemployed at all (Yes I know this is stupid, but no one ever said that the corporate world was fair or even smart.). So what you want to do is risky to your career. If you still feel like you need to do it, then do the right thing and get a new job in Chicago first and then quit. You may find you want to stay, you may decide to return to your original location, in which case you look for a new job again.  I would plan to stay about a year though as too many short stints also looks bad to hiring officials. If it take 3-6 months or longer for you to get up-to-speed and useful, quitting right after that is a losing proposition for the employer. The only things we have to go on to make those choices are your past work history.  So the less appetizing your past looks the harder it is to be taken seriously unless you are someone extraordinary (chance of this realistically are less than 1% of 1%).

Comment: I do understand your main points, and thus was my purpose of asking this thread. I really don't understand the negative attitude I've received towards this post, as I could not find a good answer. Some may deem it as "obvious" however you never know until you ask. I do deem it risky as far as my career goes, and I understand it would be a big move on behalf of the company, and I am glad you mentioned that.

Comment: @HLGEM - You might want to point out this employee with `beyond outstanding skills` had a great deal of experience ( unless they didn't ).

Comment: @ramhound, he had about 8 years of experience, but was one of those people who are just so competent that every single person he worked with would hire him back in a second. The kind of person where if you recognized his name in a stack of resumes, you would say, don't bother interviewing anyone else, heck don't bother interviewing him, just make him an offer today before he gets away. I think he is the only person I have worked with that I would say that about and I have worked with a lot of really great people.